# Python parse data with regular expressions turn into dictionary.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

I have a string of data. I would like to turn it into a
dictionary

```
ff = '{wrapper:{one:{now:""},up:"north",down:"south"}}'
```

Notice that the keys are not text wrappered with ' or ". Can regex help do this? The new text should look like below. If pandas can do this, I could
use pandas.

```
ff = '{"wrapper":{"one":{"now":""},"up":"north","down":"south"}}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a lookaround:

```
(?<={).*?(?=:)
```

where

```
(?<={)    - match { before
.*?       - non greedy
(?=:)    - match : after
```

So in code it would be..

```
import re
import json

str = '{wrapper:{one:{now:""},up:"north",down:"south"}}'
str = re.sub('(?<=[{,])(.*?)(?=:)', r'"\1"', str)
jsonobj = json.loads(str)
print jsonobj
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?!")` - negative look ahead.

```
def st_to_dict(st):
    import re
    return re.sub(r'(\b[^:"]+\b)(?!")',r'"\1"',st)

ff = '{wrapper:{one:{now:""},up:"north",down:"south"}}'

print(st_to_dict(ff))
```

Output:

```
{"wrapper":{"one":{"now":""},"up":"north","down":"south"}}
```